# Lookup values of one Pandas dataframe in another

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, and I want to do a lookup much like a Vlookup in excel.

```
df_orig.head()
   A  
0  3 
1  4  
2  6  
3  7  
4  8  


df_new
              Combined           Length  Group_name  
0   [8, 9, 112, 114, 134, 135]       6    Group 1   
1     [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]       6    Group 2   
2         [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]       5    Group 3   
3         [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]       5    Group 4   
4             [15, 16, 17, 18]       4    Group 5   
5             [8, 9, 112, 114]       4    Group 6   
6                 [18, 19, 20]       3    Group 7   
7                 [28, 29, 30]       3    Group 8   
8                     [21, 22]       2    Group 9   
9                     [28, 29]       2   Group 10   
10                    [26, 27]       2   Group 11   
11                    [24, 25]       2   Group 12   
12                      [3, 4]       2   Group 13   
13                      [6, 7]       2   Group 14   
14                    [11, 14]       2   Group 15   
15                    [12, 13]       2   Group 16   
16                      [0, 1]       2   Group 17
```

How can I add the values in `df_new["Group_name"]` to `df_orig["A"]`?

The `"Group_name"` must be based on the lookup of the values from `df_orig["A"]` in `df_new["Combined"]`.

So it would look like:

```
df_orig.head()
   A  Looked_up
0  3  Group 13
1  4  Group 13 
2  6  Group 14 
3  7  Group 14 
4  8  Group 1
```

Thank you!

Comment: Some elements (e.g. `8`) appear in more than one group, what happens then?

Comment: The ones higher up (larger list length) are more inclusive and they're the ones that must be used...The reason is that when you look at rows 1,2,3 in df_new, they're essentially the same except row 1 includes the numbers missing in 2 and 3. A Vlookup would stop at the first found match and would give the right answer. Unfortunately this is the workaround I thought I could use instead of getting rid of row 2 and 3 in favor of 1. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way which mimics a vlookup. Minimal example below.

```
import pandas as pd

df_origin = pd.DataFrame({'A': [3, 11, 0, 12, 6]})

df_new = pd.DataFrame({'Combined': [[3, 4, 5], [6, 7], [11, 14, 20],
                                    [12, 13], [3, 1], [0, 4]],
                       'Group_name': ['Group 13', 'Group 14', 'Group 15',
                                      'Group 16', 'Group 17', 'Group 18']})

df_new['ID'] = list(zip(*df_new['Combined'].tolist()))[0]

df_origin['Group_name'] = df_origin['A'].map(df_new.drop_duplicates('ID')\
                                                   .set_index('ID')['Group_name'])
```

**Result**

```
    A Group_name
0   3   Group 13
1  11   Group 15
2   0   Group 18
3  12   Group 16
4   6   Group 14
```

**Explanation**

- Extract the first element of lists in `df_new['Combined']` via `zip`.
- Use `drop_duplicates` and then create a series mapping `ID` to `Group_name`.
- Finally, use `pd.Series.map` to map `df_origin['A']` to `Group_name` via this series.

Comment: jpp, is there a way to make this solution also match the other numbers in the "Combined" list. Like if you use df_origin = pd.DataFrame({'A': [4, 5, 7, 13, 0]})

Comment: Sure, to match the second number use `df_new['ID2'] = list(zip(*df_new['Combined'].tolist()))[1]` and group by `ID2`.

Answer (score 1):

Two steps `***unnest***` + `merge`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Combined':df.Combined.sum(),'Group_name':df['Group_name'].repeat(df.Length)})

df_orig.merge(df.groupby('Combined').head(1).rename(columns={'Combined':'A'}))
Out[77]: 
   A Group_name
0  3   Group 13
1  4   Group 13
2  6   Group 14
3  7   Group 14
4  8    Group 1
```